# How to retrieve the commit message of the checked out code with Ansible?

Tags: git, ansible

I have created an Ansible Playbook for checking out code from Git repository.

How do I retrieve the latest commit message of the checked out code with Ansible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use git log to get the last commit message and save them in a variable. Something like this:

```
- name: get latest commit message
  shell: "git log --pretty="%s" -n1"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ path }}"
  register: latest_commit_message
```

Then you get the latest commit and save them in the variable `latest_commit_message`.

With `--pretty` you can define the output format you need.

Comment: It works. But, the commit message is stored in `latest_commit_message.stdout`